# jQuery, JSON, PHP and gMap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

1) I have a site, using jQuery and the [gMap](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gmap) Google Maps plugin. This all works perfectly, and I get my markers set right, and I really like this solution. This is how it looks like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MyGmapKey"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", '1.3');
        google.load("maps");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/code/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#map1").gMap(
            {
                latitude:               48.7,
                longitude:              13.4667,
                zoom:                   9,
                markers:                [{latitude: 48.461117, longitude: 13.418795, html: "MY Info Box 1"},
                   {latitude: 48.531602, longitude: 12.942087, html: "Another Info Box"},
                   {latitude: 48.198242, longitude: 13.536017, html: "Guess what? This is INFO Text!"},
                   {latitude: 48.325327094, longitude: 14.0712547302, html: "INFO"},
                   {latitude: 48.7, longitude: 13.4667,icon: { image:  "images/My_Position.png", iconsize: [20, 34], iconanchor: [5, 34], infowindowanchor: [5, 2], infoshadowanchor: [14, 25] },  html: "Your current position: 48.7 | 13.4667, Germany"}],
                controls:               ["GSmallZoomControl3D", "GMapTypeControl"],
                scrollwheel:            true,
                maptype:                G_HYBRID_MAP,
                html_prepend:           '<div class="gmap_marker">',
                html_append:            '</div>',
                icon:
                {
                  image:              "images/gmap_pin.png",
                  shadow:             false,
                  iconsize:           [19, 21],
                  shadowsize:         false,
                  iconanchor:         [4, 19],
                  infowindowanchor:   [8, 2]
                }
            });
        //Trailing "}" missing here...
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         #map1{ float:left; width:500px; height:500px; overflow:hidden; margin: 20px; }
        .gmap_marker { font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0000CC; }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Now my problem:

I added a "onmoveend" function, that will get new "marker" data from an external file. All works great, just the markers are not displaying right, only the LAST Item will be displayed. I'd bet it's only a small thing, but I am lost right now...

Here's what I do:

2) I added this script:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
    var map = $gmap;
    var center = new GLatLng(<?=$_GET['lat']?>,<?=$_GET['lon']?>);

    GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function()
    {
        map.clearOverlays();
        var center = map.getCenter();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        var lat = center.lat();
        var lng = center.lng();
        document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
        document.getElementById("lng").value = lng;

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function()
        {
            var point=marker.getPoint();
            map.panTo(point);
            var lat = point.lat();
            var lng = point.lng();
            document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
            document.getElementById("lng").value = lng;
        });

        $.getJSON('loader.php', { lat: lat, lng: lng, rad: <?=$rad?>} , function(data) {
        $("#map").gMap(
        {
            latitude:               lat,
            longitude:              lng,
            zoom:                   9,
            markers:                [data],
            controls:               ["GSmallZoomControl3D", "GMapTypeControl"], //"GScaleControl",
            scrollwheel:            true,
            maptype:                G_HYBRID_MAP,
            html_prepend:           '<div class="gmap_marker">',
            html_append:            '</div>',
            icon:
            {
              image:              "images/gmap_pin.png",
              shadow:             false,
              iconsize:           [19, 21],
              shadowsize:         false,
              iconanchor:         [4, 19],
              infowindowanchor:   [8, 2]
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And some HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="float:left; width:500px; height:500px; overflow:hidden; margin: 20px;"></div>
Current coordinates: <br>
<b>Latitude:</b> <input type="text" size="34" name="latitude" value="" id="lat" /><br>
<b>Longitude:</b><input type="text" size="34" name="longitude" value="" id="lng" />
```

If you move the first map, I display a second map which "should" hold the new markers returned by the `loader.php`.

**loader.php**:

It's getting the new "close to me" entries from the database and then "builds" the string similar to the one used in sample 1).

Here's what it looks like:

```
 $MyNewPositionMarker.='{latitude: '. $_GET['lat'].', longitude: '. $_GET['lng'].', html: "'.$html.'"},' ;
//Getting database results while
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $markers.='{latitude: '.$row['odin_facility_lat'].', longitude: '.$row['odin_facility_lon'].', html: "'.$html.'"},' ;
}

echo $markers.$MyNewPositionMarker
```

The values that are returned by `loader.php` "look" exactly what they should look like as per Sample 1).

I guess, my problem is to do with `$.getJSON` and some kind of "encode/decode" problem, but I spent all night, tried back and forth ("normal $.get"), different return formats in `loader.php`, but all NOT succeeding.

Right now, it looks OK, but unfortunately I just get the LAST marker set on my map. The jQuery Plugin, that is "setting" the markers can be found here: http://gmap.nurtext.de/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0.js

(I am turning in circles and are hoping for some clarification by you guys...)

Comment: You can see it here: http://www.divessi.com/code/geo/stack_demo.php

Comment: OK - found the first solution... 

It was, as suggested only a small thing ... 
Loader.php:  echo "[".$markers.$MyNewPositionMarker."]";

and removed the [] at the position when loading the new map:   
WRONG... markers: [data], ...
RIGHT: ...  markers: data, ...

Comment: Plz answer your question with that solution and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: please answer your own question ... preventing others of the head ache to answer it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a small thing in Loader.php:

```
echo "[".$markers.$MyNewPositionMarker."]"; 
//and removed the [] at the position when loading the new map: WRONG... markers: [data], ... RIGHT: ... markers: data, ...
```

(This is just a copy-paste of the solution in the comment to remove the question from the "unanswered" list.)