# Put marker on country

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a bunch of country names. Like hundreds. I want to add a marker on each of the countries that I have. If I use `geocoding` it says I reach the limit of requests allowed to geocode my names. So isn't there an entire "client way" of doing this without contacting the server for coordinates of the country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a kml file with the countries you want and their coordinates and then consume this in your map code.

[KML howto](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 0ptions);
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://yoursite/countries.kmz');
kmzLayer.setMap(map);
```

You can add the markers to the kml file as [in this example](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla-Google-Maps-Samples/Use-KML-file-to-place-multiple-markers-on-Google-Maps.php)

Another option would be to store your countries and geocodes in json and then iterate over the json to add the markers.

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475052/jquery-json-php-and-gmap)
Take a look at [this example](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/country_explorer/country_explorer.html) which allows you to click on a country and the country name and flag are shown.

Comment: Interesting! Would you know where I can find a KML for countries? I found one here: http://geocommons.com/overlays/101187.html but it's too large and Google tells me: `could not be displayed because it is too large`

Comment: Ok I found one that is not too big and it works: http://www.gelib.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/world-borders_nl.kml But would you know how I can interact with this KML? For example, when I load it, all the country layers are assigned. But how do I iterate through each of the layers and add a "marker" on them?